# Concurrency for objects in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, worker

I am currently working on an exercise in which I have to design a small and simple industrial factory in Java. Basically I've got a warehouse for storage, machines that produce stuff and a GUI that takes commands and informs the user of the current stockpile of the different products, etc.

I've got almost everything working, however, with the limitation that only one machine can produce at a time right now. This is probably due to my approach to the whole exercise. I wanted to start small and just coded tiny units of the program that could work independently and then pieced them together one after another adding more and more logic to the application and implementing all the communication between the different classes, etc.

Now I am at the point where everything seems to be fine and the only thing left to do is to establish concurrency so that I can run several machines at the same time without any problems.

To give you a better understand, I'll try to outline my applications structure:

First there's a GUI and a GUI Controller that assigns the tasks wanted by the user to the other Controllers in the application. It also manages the updates for the GUI (stockpile, ...)

Then I've got the warehouse section with the actual warehouse (HSQLDB, file based, JDBC connection) and a storageController, which controls all tasks regarding the warehouse (store products, remove products, get the stock, ...)

And finally there is the machine section. 
There are 3 types of machines. Each type differs only in the product produced. Type 1 and 3 produce the raw products needed for type 2 to produce a final product.

In order to create as many machines as one likes to, I decided to use a Abstract Factory pattern to implement them. That means that I've got an abstractMachineFactory, which holds all the needed attributes (like a machine ID, its status (on/off), ...) and methods including an abstract method "produce(boolean status)". Status = true means that the machine is producing, false means that it's not.

I gave each of the machine types its own class, so that I've got concreteMachineType1, concreteMachineType2 and concreteMachineType3. In there the "produce()" method is implemented specifically to the machine type, i.e. type2's method checks (via the machineController) if there is a big enough stockpile of the raw products that type1 and 3 produce so that it can begin producing.
As the machines should be continually producing, the body executes "while (status=true)". If  the stockpile is not big enough, the machine will check again after a certain timeout (via the controller).

And now we come to the machineController. This controller manages all tasks regarding the individual machines. That means creating them, starting/stopping a single or all machines, get supplies from the warehouse, bring the final product from the interim storage to the warehouse, etc.

In order to identify and access my machines, I've implemented different array lists (one for each machine type) in which the machine objects are stored, with the index of the array being the machines' ID. This way I can start/stop a specific machine by accessing the index or start/stop all by parsing through the whole array list.

When starting the machines I also execute the "produce()" method and this is where the problem is at the moment (in my opinion).

This is what happens: I create a few new machines (default is that they are turned off) and then execute my startAllMachines() method. What this method will do is parsing through the array list and executing startMachine() on every single machine object in that list. As said above, startMachine() also calls the produce() method of the machine.

And now I'm basically in an infinite loop, as the produce() method of that machine will run as long as I turn it off, by setting its status value to false. That means that all other machines will not be turned on, so that only this single machine will produce and the rest is in a queue that will never be reached.

I figure that I need different threads to work all machines concurrently, so that each machine is started by a different thread. The problem is that I have no clue on how to achieve this and the basic tutorials I've found didn't help me either. Most of them suggested implementing Runable() and defining a run() method, but this isn't applicable in my scenario (imho). What I think I need is concurrent machine starter objects or something.

I hope some of you can give me hints in how to proceed here.

best regards
daZza

Comment: That's a lot to read.

Comment: Indeed, but I wanted to try and outline the whole concept briefly so that you understand why I need what I need. Also from what I could gather on this platform, the people generally appreciate details/concepts and are more likely to help you when you can provide them. I don't want anyone to do my "homework" for me, I've got most of it done (surprisingly enough :P) and just want to get some tips on how to solve that last problem, as concurrency seems to be one of the more complex topics in the world of coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Machine {

private Thread producerThread;

/**
 * Non blocking method that produces fixed amount of stuff and returns.
 */
private void produceStuff() {
    // TODO
}

private void startProducing() {
    Runnable producingTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            produce();
        }
    };

    producerThread = new Thread(producingTask);

    producerThread.start();
}

private void stopProducing() {
    if (producerThread != null) {
        producerThread.interrupt();
    }

}

/**
 * Check cancellation every time stuff is produced.
 */
private void produce() {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        produceStuff();
    }
}

public void start() {
    startProducing();
}

public void stop() {
    stopProducing();
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks mate. Will try to implement it first thing tomorrow.